# Python: After linking texture to material how do I add it to blenders texture list?

Tags: python, import

So I have created an image texture using python in 2.80, and linked it to the material and that shows fine.

However in the property editor under texture it does not show up in the list.

I tried many things, and cannot find an answer online.

Does anyone know how to do that?

```py
texIm = material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texIm.image = self.loadImage("test")
#how to add that to the texture list in property editor?
```

Comment: Image nodes in material are not textures like the one you have in the properties editor. They are material only textures. Why do you need to add them in the properties editor texture list?

Comment: I am just used to having all the scenes textures in that dropdown list. Maybe its a workflow thing from 2.79..